# ASP.NET Checkbox Text not aligned right or left to the Checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, layout, checkbox, alignment

In the new Visual Studio 2012 Webforms Templates all my ASP.NET Checkboxes and Radiobuttons have the Text on top or on bottom.

Is the intended!? How can i align the text right as it always was? I tried disable theming and set the cssclass to checkbox but nothing changed.

**Solution found**: I researched the html in firebug and it seems that the default Microsoft CSS is broken(!) label { display: block; } causes the wrong aligment

[image]

Comment: What theme is that for visual studio?

Comment: dark theme. there are only light and dark by default ;)

Comment: Im guessing 2012 only right? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is styling issue. Maybe the page viewport is too small and that results in what you see.

If setting properties in asp.net does not help, then it can definitely be solved by css.
After all, output is good old html...

Comment: yes, i researched the html in firebug and it seems that the default Microsoft CSS is broken(!) label {
display: block; } causes the wrong aligment

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same issue.

My ASP.NET Web Forms project was created using VS2012 and uses the default templates and stylesheets that were added.  The issue exists on a new page/form that I created.  My form controls happen to reside in TABLE cells.  Here is what I did to work around the issue:

- Created a new stylesheet called CoreFrameworkTweaks.css that contains this code:

  .checkbox label {
      display: inline;
      margin-left: 3px;
      font-size: 1.0em;
  }
- Referenced the new stylesheet in my master page *** AFTER *** Site.css gets pulled in
- Ensured all controls in my form were wrapped with `<fieldset></fieldset>`
- Added the CssClass="checkbox" parameter to my checkbox control

Issue fixed.

Comment: yes, the simplest solution is simply to change label display to inline

Answer (score 2):

In the `style.css` file go and search for:

```
label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

then replace it with:

```
label {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: same problem when using asp.net 4 default template

Answer (score 2):

Site.css has code:

```
fieldset.login label, fieldset.register label, fieldset.changePassword label
{
    display:  block;
}

fieldset label.inline
{
    display: inline;
}
```

you need find Checkbox in Login.aspx and add CssClass="inline" to Label

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" EnableTheming="True" />
<asp:Label ID="RememberMeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" 
    CssClass="inline">RememberMe</asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a `TextAlign` property on them. You can set it here.

If this doesn't make any difference then you must have some `CSS` causing the issue.

Comment: Textalign property is set to right. Nothing changes. CSS is the default from the template. Commenting the css styles out nothing changes too.

Comment: What development environment is that? just curious.. anyway, i can see that your HTML for the checkbox doesn't have TextAlign="Right" explicitly added. have you tried that?....ignore me, just noticed VS 2012 ... long day :)

Comment: and default from what template? Perhaps you could update your question with a little more code?

Comment: TextAlign="Right" is the default. Also explicitly setting it doesn't change it. You can see all code in the screenshot.

Comment: @zoidbergi - what i can see in the screenshot is <asp:checkbox Id="checkbox1" runat="server" text="fsdafsda" /> - I don't see TextAlign="Right" in there.. I see it in the properties on the right, though have you confirmed the actual source generated when you run the site?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for this. I was stuck with this problem for the longest time! The problem occurs for **both checkboxes as well as radiobuttons.**

All you need to do is find site.css in folder Content. Find the following:

```
label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

and replace it with

```
label {
    /*display: block;*/
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
label {
        display: inline !important;
      }
```