# get checkbox text on same line as control using asp:CheckBox control

Tags: css, asp.net

I have found numerous references to this but still cannot get it to work.
Several people have pointed to a previous post from 7 years ago that has a similar sounding problem but as detailed below the solution for that does not work at all.

I have the following asp code:

```
<asp:CheckBox id="checkbox1" runat="server" Style="display:inline;"
     AutoPostBack="True" Text="Send Emails" TextAlign="Right"/>
```

It displays like this:

[image: bad display]

If I go into the elements explorer in Chrome I see the following:

[image]

If I manually add the style attribute to the input line like this (using the Chrome Elements right click menu), it works:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Update:  This is the "solution" I wound up doing:

```
 <div >
   <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1"  style="display: inline"/>
   <label for="checkbox1">I would like to receive periodic email</label>
 </div>
```

While this works it is obviously just avoiding the question entirely by switching to a HTML control vs ASP.

Comment: Similar Question on SO [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315165/asp-net-checkbox-text-not-aligned-right-or-left-to-the-checkbox)

Comment: That is not really accurate, and your link is to a question from 7 years ago that only partially relates to my current issue.

Thank you for the effort and the edit, but the link does not address this current problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asp:CheckBox checkbox and text are not on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891681/aspcheckbox-checkbox-and-text-are-not-on-the-same-line)

Comment: No, I had found that one already also.  It produces exactly the same result.  I have tried about 5 others off of Stack Overflow already also -- I have literally spent about 3 hours researching and trying things.  I just feel dumb telling the client that after designing an entire system for them I can't figure this out!  :)

Comment: have you tried `Style="display:inline !important;"`

Comment: I am not sure what would adding !important have to do with it?
I did try that before, and I just tried it again and it does not have any impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a solution. As `asp:CheckBox` creating three controls and the ID is `checkbox1` try the css for ID's

```
#checkbox1
{
   display:inline !important;   
}
```

This should work properly.

Comment: Accepting this as it pointed me the right direction.
Posting working code in the question also.